# How to make timers with SQL?

Tags: sql, timer

How can I make timers with sql?
So for example if I give it 120 seconds so after 120 seconds the value will be 0 or removed.
I know the way of making updates every second... But this is bad and will cause massive lags on the server.
Thanks!

Comment: You would really need to give some more context, because what you are describing is something that really shouldn't be done with SQL.  However, it's possible that I'm just not seeing the context.

Comment: @BigDevJames I need to make global cooldown for a few servers.

Comment: @BigDevJames and I am running a program that can save the data to "ram" but all will be lost when I close the program. This is why I want to make it with sql...

Answer (score -1):

For MySQL, you can use Event Scheduler.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html